# Add Item from another class to a property from another class. Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, methods, properties

So I have two classes. When press the save button, it will pass down the value from `self.screen.text` by `addItem` method to the `totalArray` in class 2. If I try to `NSLog` in the `@implementation` of `addItem` method, then it will give out the correct output but If I do it in `viewDidLoad`, the output is null. How can I save the value passing from class1 to property of class2 permanently? Thank you. The class2 in a subclass of UITableViewController

Class 1 @interface

```
//class1.h
#import class2.h
@interface class1 : superclass {

}

- (IBAction)buttonSave:(id)sender;
```

Class1 @implementation

```
//class1.m
@interface class1 ()

@end

@implementation class1 {

}

- (IBAction)buttonSave:(id)sender {
  class2 *Obj = [[class2 alloc] init];
  [Obj addItem:self.screen.text];
}
```

And class2 @interface

```
//class2.h
#import class2.h
@interface {

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *totalArray;
```

class2 @implementation

```
@interface class2 ()

@end

@implementation {

}

- (void) addItem:(id)item {
  self.totalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //alloc & init
  [self.totalArray addObject:item]; //add object to the total array
  // NSLog(@"%@", self.totalArray); If I NSLog in within this method then everything works as expected.
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSLog(@"%@", self.totalArray); //But in here the output is null. ???

}
```

Comment: How do you show class2 view ? Share some code please

Comment: I know this is a stupid question but what do you mean by show the view?

Comment: implementing `viewDidLoad` in class2 means class2 is a UIViewController right ?
If it is not, are you really sure that `viewDidLoad` is called ?

Comment: the viewDidLoad method is in my UITableViewController and and when I press a button in the first view controller, it pushes to UITableViewController. Class2 is UITableViewController.

Comment: Ok, then could you please share the code of this button ?

Comment: The button is in navigation bar (by UINavigationController) which links to class2 UITableViewController by interface builder (push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your problem is that you have use a different class2 object. The one that you had init in buttonSave, is not the one that you are displaying

add a property in class1.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *savedArray;
```

and modify buttonSave :

```
- (IBAction)buttonSave:(id)sender {
      self.savedArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
      [self.savedArray addObject:self.screen.text];
}
```

You are using a storyboard, then please try to add this in class1.h and add an identifier `class2Segue` to this segue in your storyboard :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"class2Segue"]) 
    {
        Class2 *tableController = (Class2 *)[segue destinationViewController];
        tableController.totalArray = self.savedArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't assign a string NSString * to NSArray. Incompatible pointer type.

Comment: I try to NSLog(@"%@", self.totalArray); in class2 both viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear but the value is still null.

Comment: Keep your NSLog in class2 viewDidLoad. If it still say null, verify that your segue id is correct :) (or it won't enter in `if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"class2Segue"])`

Comment: Yes thank god, thank you!!!! It works now. Just let me playing around with it a little bit more and I'll mark your answer as right.

Comment: I changed the property NSArray * savedArray to NSMutableArray

Comment: @Kawin great :). Just be careful about allocating a new Array in `buttonSave`, be sure that it's what you want.
@Kawin thx, for the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this...

```
- (IBAction)buttonSave:(id)sender 
    {
      class2 *Obj = [[class2 alloc] init];

      Obj.totalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //alloc & init
      [Obj.totalArray addObject:self.screen.text];
      NSLog(@"screen.text %@", self.screen.text); // -- check here it may be null---- 
      NSLog(@"Obj.totalArray %@", Obj.totalArray);

    }

    @interface class2 ()

    @end

    @implementation {

    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
     {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      NSLog(@"%@", self.totalArray); //But in here the output is null. ???

    }
```

Comment: I got an error: No visible @interface 'NSMutableArray' declares the selector 'addItem'.

Comment: The error has gone away now but the output from NSLog is still null

Comment: See my edited answer i think there is null value in self.screen.text So please follow me..

Comment: no the output value is correct. I don't know why when I go to class2 (UITableViewController) the output is null. There are some value in the self.screen.text. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidLoad` is called after `init` so you array is `nil` here. Change your `class2` `init` method to accept the item.

```
// In class2
-(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style andItem:(id)item {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if(self) {
        self.totalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self.totalArray addObject:item];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Your addItem will then look like,

```
- (void) addItem:(id)item {
  //Just add, do not initialize again
  [self.totalArray addObject:item];
}
```

The button action in class1 will now look like,

```
- (IBAction)buttonSave:(id)sender {
    class2 *Obj = [[class2 alloc] initWithItem:self.screen.text];
    //OR
    //class2 *Obj = [[class2 alloc] initWithItem:UITableViewStylePlain andItem:self.screen.text];
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I forgot to mention that my class2 is a subclass of UITableViewController so it doesn't have initWithItem, I only see initWithStyle. What can I do here? thanks

Comment: `viewDidLoad`
 is called when `view` property is needed by the controller. You can't say that `viewDidLoad` is called after `init`, since it may never get called

Comment: @KIDdAe Yes true. But, in this case `viewDidLoad` is getting called, and it will surely get called after `init`.

Comment: class2 doesn't have -(id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style andItem:(id)item method declare in the header file, should I add it?

Comment: @Kawin Yes you should add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not ensure when your `viewDidLoad` method will call... so better pass the value to the init method and set there `initWithText:(NSString*)text{}`. Other wise try to call NSLog in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` just for testing purpose. In iOS 7 now presentation of view-controllers is bit changed now.